# Using Select-String against a server list

Tags: powershell

I have a serverlist which contains all server names on a single line. Each server has the exact path and file as listed in the following:

```
$Computers = get-content "c:\temp\serverlist.txt"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
  select-string "F:\xxx\SmarXXXX\yyyyyyations\xxxxx\servers\data-sources.xml" `
    -pattern "thisiswhatimsearchingfor"
}
```

I edited the actual code with xxxxx since some of it may be considered sensitive. When I run this command I am given the string that I am looking for, but there is no link to which server returns this data. I essentially need to find out which servers from my serverlist do NOT contain the pattern requested.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks for your patience.

EDIT:
I have come up with the following but it does not display the desired output. This returns just the strings, but not the servers that it is pulling them from. Thanks for the help. I attempted to add the where-object in order to see the associated server with each string. This failed.

```
$Computers = get-content "c:\temp\serverlist.txt"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
 Select-String "F:\xx\xxxxxxPath\applications\yyyyyyy\servers\data-xxxx.xml" -pattern "render" | where {($_ -match "render") 
}
}
```

Comment: Does the either parameter to `select-string` depend on `$Computer` somehow? Otherwise it seems the output of the `select-string` will just be repeated once for each line in `serverlist.txt`.

Comment: Are you trying to check if that particular path exists on any of the servers in your serverlist?

Comment: I am looking for the desired string in the .xml files which is held in the same location on every server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNC paths and a filter to get a list of computers where the search pattern occurs in the file:

```
$file = 'F$\xxx\SmarXXXX\yyyyyyations\xxxxx\servers\data-sources.xml'

Get-Content "c:\temp\serverlist.txt" | ? {
  (Get-Content "\\$_\$file") -match 'search pattern'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\serverlist.txt | where { 
  -not ( $_ -match "thisiswhatimsearchingfor" ) 
}
```

Comment: will test this out once I get back to the office tomorrow. thanks so much!!

Comment: no dice. this outputs an identical list to the server list even though I know half of them do not have the required string. thanks for the input.